# Best way to work with large array or large table

Tags: php, arrays

I have table `arseh` with 10,000,000 record.

I need select from this table more than 10,000.

For increase speed I select all records from database and fill in global array,
and then search in global array

```
         Arseh Table
------------------------------
|BlockCode|ID|FromYear|ToYear|
-----------------------------
|01011001 |1 |1350    |1395  |
|01250110 |1 |1355    |1366  |
|01020201 |10|1395    |1395  |
```

```
$ListMyArseBooklet = array();

function myselectArsehPriceBooklet($Year, $BlockCode, $ID) {
    $Handler = new DB();
    global $ListMyArseBooklet;

    if (empty($ListMyArseBooklet)) {
        //select from data base all data to global variable 
        $table = "arseh";
        $fields = "*";
        $ListMyArseBooklet = $baseClass - > select($table, $fields);
        //====================== 
    }

    //search value in array
    foreach($ListMyArseBooklet as $key => $R) {
            if ($R["BlockCode"] == $BlockCode && $R["ID"] == $ID && $R["FromYear"] <= $Year && $R["ToYear"] >= $Year)
                return $R;
    }
    //=====================
}
```

I call this function more than 10,000.

**Problem**: search time is about 10 seconds (I checked it). Is there a way that decrease this time?

Comment: Can you please post the structure of your table.

Comment: Does it take 10 seconds to query mysql directly? Are you fetching all 10 million rows? If so, why not limit your select, or add a where clause. If using a where, check there is an index on the fields you are selecting and filtering for.

Comment: You're not being very specific when it comes to your 'search time'. Am I right in assuming it takes 10 seconds to load the 10.000.000 records and then use `myselectArsehPriceBooklet()` once? So most of the time is spent retrieving the records?

Comment: no, i check that this time is for search

Comment: You have a database and you're performing a search using PHP's array? What the f....

Comment: *"For increase speed"*: evidently not. Note that databases are particularly good in searching results. The logic of the `foreach` loop at the end is something that databases can do faster; certainly if you have the indexes defined correctly.

Comment: What are you searching for? where do `$Year, $BlockCode, $ID` come from? Another sql table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your time taken is long because you are selecting everything and then searching in PHP, which is really bad idea.  Databases are built to search are return sets of records... which is what you should do... especially as you are returning one record only each time... something like this...

```
$stmt =  $mysqli->stmt_init();
if ($stmt->prepare("
    SELECT * 
    FROM table 
    WHERE BlockCode = ? 
        AND ID = ?
        AND ? NOT BETWEEN FromYear AND ToYear
    LIMIT 1
")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$BlockCode);
    $stmt->bind_param('i',$ID);
    $stmt->bind_param('i',$Year);
    $stmt->execute();

    //use the output

    $stmt->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
```

The reason it is slower as you have it is that the database must take all the records and send them over the pipe to PHP that has to hold/process them and then do the logic of the search to get the result.  It's like taking all books in the library home and searching for one of them, instead of just taking the single book home from the library.

Also using prepared statements helps the system optimized the query for each subsequent time it is run, instead of looking at the query as new each time.

Lastly depending on the exact DBMS there are many indexes, caches and storage methods to investigate as well to speed up the database end of the operation to make returning that one record faster.

If you are *only* focused on the PHP side of things (which isn't clear in your question but hinted at) then you are going to want to investigate sorting algorithms and data structures.  For example, if the BlockCode is the most important factor int eh search then create a binary tree using the BlockCode and you will see a performance gain in storing / searching the data that way... but still strongly suspect focusing on the database is best.

Comment: "I call this function more than 10,000" - executing 10K SQL queries might perform worse than the original PHP solution. Even if you prepare the statement once outside of the function, it will still take a lot of time.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel without the exact data there is always a "might".  If the DB instance is gaining something in knowing the query and sending the same data... I'd still say that using the database for the search and returning fewer (matched) records is less overall CPU cycles and faster.  There are many other solutions which will be specific to the dataset... but I'm happy the above is the best generic solution that can be given without having the dataset to test on.

Comment: I'd also point out that OP hasn't given a specific database (I'm assuming MySQL), depending on the exact DBMS there are many indexes, caches and storage methods to investigate as well

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - a universe where PHP only solution performs better than 10 000 queries (by using prepared statements) doesn't exist yet. If in doubt, feel free to test. Opinion is worth nothing, facts are everything.